# Solve the differential equation $y'-y\tan(x)=6$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the differential equation

$$y'-y\tan(x)=6$$

Solve equation above and state the validity of the answer. How should I approach this problem.

Comment: Hint: Find an integral factor.

Comment: @ÁngelMarioGallegos I did but the answer wolfram gives is different to mine.

Comment: @ÁngelMarioGallegos the equation is linear with y right?

Comment: @TalalKamran Can you state the answer that you got and the answer WolframAlpha provided to you?  Is there perhaps a chance that the two answers are equivalent?

Comment: @benguin I got y=(6ln|secx+tanx|+c)/secx

Comment: @benguin wolfram gave me y=csecx+6tanx

Comment: I think you need to check your integrating factor.

Comment: What do you think the integral of $\tan$ is?

Comment: @Ian ln|secx|+c

Comment: OK, so $e^{\ln(|\sec(x)|}=$?

Comment: @Ian e^ln(|sec(x)| = secx

Comment: @Ian Then I get y'secx-tanxsecxy=6secx
d/dx(ysec(x))= 6secx

Comment: Oh, I forgot about the minus sign. Did you notice that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45333/discussion-between-talal-kamran-and-ian).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

multiply through by $\cos x$ before doing anything else

Comment: Why should I do that?

Comment: It worked, but what made you think of multiplying through by cosx rather than just following the steps?

Comment: @TalalKamran try $y' + y  = \frac {3 x^2}{e^x}$

Comment: Ah the y' + y on the left hand side were the clue

Comment: y= x^3/exp(1)!!

Comment: The integrating factor was $e^{-\ln (sec (x))} $ which is $cos (x) $.